# I want to make a button display an image based on a property set in my view controller.m

Tags: ios, iphone, methods, ios7

I'm fairly new to iOS programming and I have a question..

I'm in a situation right now where I want to have a set of buttons display an image based on the property "name" I have given them. There are three kinds of names and i want the buttons to display the image that suits the name.

So in my button class I have set up this method :

```
-(void) checkName {
if([self.name isEqualToString:@"v60"]){
      [recipeImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v60.png"]]];
}

else if([self.name isEqualToString:@"aeropress"]){
      [recipeImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aeropress.png"]]];
}

else if([self.name isEqualToString:@"chemex"]){
    [recipeImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chemex.png"]]];
}
}
```

In my recipeButton.h I have set up the property like this :

```
@property (strong) NSString *name;
```

and in my recipeButton.m I have synthesized it like this :

```
@synthesize name;
```

in my view controller I give my buttons the name property like this :

```
recipeButton *recipeButton1 = [[recipeButton alloc] init];
[recipeButton1 setTitle:@"Brewology V60" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[recipeButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(pushExample)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
recipeButton1.name =@"v60";
```

anybody help me? The images don't show and I think I'm missing something very important.

Comment: When is called `checkName`?

Comment: I call checkname in my recipeButton class in the ViewDidLoad

Comment: `recipteButton` inherits from? Because it seems to be a button, and doesn't have `viewDidLoad` method. Is `viewDidLoad` even called?

Comment: ooh yeah my recipeButton doesn't have a viewDidLoad hehe because it's a UIButton

Comment: Call the `checkName` function from outside, because I feel it is not getting called or, you are calling in wrong place call it after you are setting `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) checkName 
{
    [recipeImage setBackgroundImage:[self getImage:@"name Property"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(UIImage *)getImage:(NSString *)property
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",property]];
    return image;
}
```